How to Transform one table value with Group by Using CTE
I need to convert one table data as follows



NO
Name
Position
Group




1
John
Painter
India


2
MArk
Washer
India


3
Peter
Officer
Nepal


4
Angel
Officer
India


5
Bibin
Washer
Nepal


6
Jerry
Painter
Nepal


7
Lilly
Painter
India


8
George
Washer
India


9
Abrahm
Officer
Nepal


10
Bosan
Officer
India


11
Jemi
Painter
Nepal


12
Jerry
Washer
Nepal



above table to get the following result



NO
Painter
Painter
Washer
Washer
Officer
Officer




--
India
Nepal
India
Nepal
India
Nepal


--
--
--
--
----
--
-----


1
John
Jerry
Mark
Bibib
Peter
Angel


2
Lilly
Jemi
George
Jerry
Abrahm
Bosan



Under Each position need to distribute the name with group wise
 create table #Temp
( SLno int,
Name  varchar(20),
Postion  varchar(20),
Groups Varchar(2))



INsert into #Temp Values (1 ,'John  ','Painter  ','India')
INsert into #Temp Values (2 ,'MArk  ','Washer   ','India')
INsert into #Temp Values (3 ,'Peter ','Officer  ','Nepal')
INsert into #Temp Values (4 ,'Angel ','Officer  ','India')
INsert into #Temp Values (5 ,'Bibin ','Washer   ','Nepal')
INsert into #Temp Values (6 ,'Jerry ','Painter  ','Nepal')
INsert into #Temp Values (7 ,'Lilly ','Painter  ','India')
INsert into #Temp Values (8 ,'George',' Washer  ','India')
INsert into #Temp Values (9 ,'Abrahm',' Officer ','Nepal')
INsert into #Temp Values (10,'Bosan','  Officer ','India')
INsert into #Temp Values (11,'Jemi  ','Painter  ','Nepal')
INsert into #Temp Values (12,'Jerry','  Washer  ','Nepal')


DECLARE @Columns VARCHAR(MAX) = ''
SELECT @Columns = @Columns + ',' + QUOTENAME( Postion ) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Postion FROM #Temp) T
SELECT @Columns = STUFF(@Columns, 1,1,'')
Print @Columns
DECLARE @SqlText VARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT * FROM #Temp 
PIVOT ( (Groups) FOR Name IN ('+ @Columns +')) AS PVT'


Why with CTE? Surely it's PIVOT you want?

yes , PIVOT I need

Have you tried using a pivot?

no, i try using CTE but not able to get the end result.

Please try using pivot

This is something we usually don't do in SQL, but in the application. Mainly because a query decribes a recult table, so the resulting columns must be known when writing the query. Here, however, I guess you want the result to build dynamically from the groups and positions that happen to be in the table when running the query.

@ThorstenKettner, yes dynamically convert the data to position under each group

Can you show us what your have tried?

Simply use your app or website to loop through your data and display the result in the desired layout. The other option is dynamic SQL, which means you have a query to get all groups and positions, then you loop through them to build another query with these columns.

@Alex i updated with i tried

@ThorstenKettner in frond end i tried with linq process but it taking long time to execute the result , but the end result is getting wrong.

@ThorstenKettner can you help me to develop the dynamic query for this

I would just read the data and loop through it in my app. That's the simplest approach here. The result rows don't contain related information, as is typical for SQL, so it is way better to just read the data as is and then care about the layout in your app. NO|TM|TM|SA|SA|... shows no relation. You'd have to tell the DBMS which column to give which value. NO|A|B|A|B|... again shows no relation, again something to tell the DBMS in the query. --|--|--|... this is not even data. John|Jerry|Mark are not related either. They just happen to be the first ones picked per group and position.

In other words: The final query that you would want to build from the columns and positions is already quite complicated. You'd have to relate names fist, probably by numbering them per group and positions, just to be able to start. As mentioned: Just loop through your data instead. This will get it easier to write and easier to understand and maintain.

@ThorstenKettner updated with Values

But still the same applies. You show John with Jerry, but you could just as well show him with Jemi. It is more or less an arbitrary, because John is not related to either of them.

I believe you have your Officer/India and Officer/Nepal columns reversed in your desired results. Peter and Abrahm belong with Nepal. ANgel and Bosan belong with India.

@TN yes same, and your answer solve my issue.

SQL queries do not support multi-row column headers, so you will have to settle for column headers like TM_A and SA_B and leave the final header formatting to the presentation layer.
This is not a typical simple PIVOT use case because:

The result columns represent a combination of two source columns,
The source does not contain a row grouping value.

For resolve the first issue, we can use CONCAT() to build a combined value for use in the pivot.
For the second issue, we need to assign unique sequential row numbers to each value that will appear in the same column. This can be done using the ROW_NUMBER() window function with an appropriate OVER() clause to partition the data by target column and to define the order. I will assume that names should be assigned in SLNo order.
The combined column key and row numbers can be calculated in a CTE that also includes the Name column that will fill in the body of the results. Other columns are omitted. This CTE now is in a form that can be fed into the PIVOT.
The result would be something like:
WITH CTE_NumberedPositions AS (
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Position, [Group] ORDER BY SLNo) AS No,
        CONCAT(Position, '_', [Group]) AS Combined,
        Name
    FROM #Temp
)
SELECT
    No,
    [Painter_India], [Painter_Nepal], [Washer_India], [Washer_Nepal], [Officer_India], [Officer_Nepal]
FROM CTE_NumberedPositions
PIVOT (
    MAX(Name)
    FOR Combined IN ([Painter_India], [Painter_Nepal], [Washer_India], [Washer_Nepal], [Officer_India], [Officer_Nepal])
) PVT
ORDER BY PVT.No

The same can also be achieved using conditional aggregation, which eliminates the need to pre-calculate a combined column key.
WITH CTE_NumberedPositions AS (
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Position, [Group] ORDER BY SLNo) AS No
    FROM #Temp
)
SELECT
    No,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Position = 'Painter' AND [Group] = 'India' THEN Name END) AS [Painter_India],
    MAX(CASE WHEN Position = 'Painter' AND [Group] = 'Nepal' THEN Name END) AS [Painter_Nepal],
    MAX(CASE WHEN Position = 'Washer' AND [Group] = 'India' THEN Name END) AS [Washer_India],
    MAX(CASE WHEN Position = 'Washer' AND [Group] = 'Nepal' THEN Name END) AS [Washer_Nepal],
    MAX(CASE WHEN Position = 'Officer' AND [Group] = 'India' THEN Name END) AS [Officer_India],
    MAX(CASE WHEN Position = 'Officer' AND [Group] = 'Nepal' THEN Name END) AS [Officer_Nepal]
FROM CTE_NumberedPositions
GROUP BY No
ORDER BY No

If your Postion and Groups values are not known ahead of time, you will have identify all of the distinct Postion and Groups values up front and use dynamic SQL to generate and execute queries equivalent to the above:
DECLARE @Columns NVARCHAR(MAX) = (
    SELECT STRING_AGG(QUOTENAME(CONCAT(A.Position, '_', B.[Group])), ', ')
        WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY A.Position, B.[Group])
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Position FROM #Temp) A
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT [Group] FROM #Temp) B
)

DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = '
    WITH CTE_NumberedPositions AS (
        SELECT
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Position, [Group] ORDER BY SLNo) AS No,
            CONCAT(Position, ''_'', [Group]) AS Combined,
            Name
        FROM #Temp
    )
    SELECT
        No, 
        ' + @Columns + '
    FROM CTE_NumberedPositions
    PIVOT (
        MAX(Name)
        FOR Combined IN (' + @Columns + ')
    ) PVT
    ORDER BY PVT.No
'

PRINT @Sql
EXEC (@Sql)

or
DECLARE @Columns NVARCHAR(MAX) = (
    SELECT STRING_AGG(S.Item, ',' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10))
        WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY A.Position, B.[Group])
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Position FROM #Temp) A
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT [Group] FROM #Temp) B
    CROSS APPLY (
         SELECT item =
              '        MAX(CASE WHEN Position = '
              + QUOTENAME(A.Position, '''')
              + ' AND [Group] = '
              + QUOTENAME(B.[Group], '''')
              + ' THEN Name END) AS '
              + QUOTENAME(CONCAT(A.Position, '_', B.[Group]))
    ) S
)

DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = '
    WITH CTE_NumberedPositions AS (
        SELECT *,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Position, [Group] ORDER BY SLNo) AS No
        FROM #Temp
    )
    SELECT
        No,
' + @Columns + '
    FROM CTE_NumberedPositions
    GROUP BY No
    ORDER BY No
'

PRINT @Sql
EXEC (@Sql)

Note the use of QUOTENAME() for injecting both generated column names and quoted values. This is needed to ensure valid SQL is generated if the data contains odd values containing spaces, apostrophes, or other special characters. It also protects against SQL injection attacks.
Sample results (with some extra test data):



No
Painter_India
Painter_Nepal
Washer_India
Washer_Nepal
Officer_India
Officer_Nepal




1
John
Jerry
MArk
Bibin
Angel
Peter


2
Lilly
Jemi
George
Jerry
Bosan
Abrahm


3
null
Curly
null
Moe
null
Larry



With dynamic SQL, the results are the same, but the column order may be different:



No
Officer_India
Officer_Nepal
Painter_India
Painter_Nepal
Washer_India
Washer_Nepal




1
Angel
Peter
John
Jerry
MArk
Bibin


2
Bosan
Abrahm
Lilly
Jemi
George
Jerry


3
null
Larry
null
Curly
null
Moe



You may need to adjust the dynamic SQL logic if you need the columns in a different order.
See this db<>fiddle for a demo.
